# How to get device key using device id from IoT hub using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I have created a IoT hub in Azure.

Register a device into IoT hub using below code -

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RegisterDeviceAsyncData(DeviceData deviceApp)
        {
            

                        deviceApp.PlatformName = _appSettingsAccessor.GetAppSettingValue(DEFAULT_HUB_KEY);
   


                    var result = await _deviceRegistrationHandler.RegisterDeviceAsync(deviceApp);
               

                response = HttpResponseMessageFactory.CreateMessageWithObjectBody(results);
            }
```

it is successfully registering devices into Iot hub, now I want to send data to these devices using C#.

I have code to send data to device below but I don't know how to get connection string of particular device or key to send data.

```
 private static async Task SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync()
        {
    DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("deviceConnectionString");
            while (true)
            {

                string messageString = string.Empty;
                Message iotHubMsg = new Message();

                foreach (BaseMessage msg in currentDevice.Messages)
                {


                        iotHubMsg = msg.ReadAsIotHubMessage();

                    messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(iotHubMsg.GetBytes());

                        //Send the current messages and clear them
                        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(iotHubMsg);
                        }
                        }
                        }
```

For now I tried to get connection string using portal.azure.com, but in real time after register device how can I retrieve a connection string? Can I use a SAS token or something like that?

Comment: doesn't the result of registering the device give you a device id? The client will need to persist that for future requests.

Comment: i'm getting device id back because i'm inserting it from request but how to get key / secret key / primary key i mean key is also there into connection string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to solve this issue with one of these approaches:

1. Using a generic device connection string:

   a) go to IoT Hub and from 'Shared access policies" get a connection string for the 'device' policy *(e.g. HostName=iothub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=device;SharedAccessKey=abcd1234)*

   b) This is a generic connection string. If you add "DeviceId=" it would be specific to your device and IotHub would be able to identify your new/existing device *(e.g. HostName=iothub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=device;SharedAccessKey=abcd1234;DeviceId=device001)*
2. Using automatic device provisioning with the help of [Azure Device provisioning Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps). I have never personally used it, but it should be working. Furthermore, this should be the approach if you have a really big number of devices.

Hopefully, this helps you.

Comment: i can get the connection string for specific device from azure portal true , but i want it using code because after register device i will send event data to that device and how can i send data to that particular device which is created right now?

Comment: when you create the device you should be providing the deviceId, right? If this is true, then using my first approach you can build your connection `deviceConnectionString` using the generic one. The generic one should be in your local configuration. You can even try developing a single repository (e.g. REST API) that will give you the generic connection string. In this way you can easily change the key for all devices periodically.

Comment: wow thats a great thing I was trying to use this code and this is also working but your approach make sense thanks a lot :)
` deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(deviceid, deviceKey), TransportType.Mqtt);`

Comment: I'm no expert, but I feel like using the shared device connection string leaves you vulnerable to spoofing device Ids - meaning, anyone with that shared string can connect as any device. With a device-specific string, you have to use the key for that device, and that would be more secure.

Comment: In fact, the accepted answer here is something MS advises against: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-device-oem-security-practices#shared-symmetric-key